# initial state in a dynamic_rnn as a placeholder

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I'd like to enter the tensor to the intial_state of an LSTM as a placeholder so that later on I assign it's value myself during the learning process.

I wrote the following:

```
import tensorflow as tf
class PGNetwork:
def __init__(self, inpsize, name='PGNetwork'):
    tf.reset_default_graph()
    self.inpsize = inpsize

    with tf.variable_scope(name):
        # We create the placeholders
        self.inputs_vec = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 
                            self.inpsize], name="inputs_vec")
        self.in_state = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [1, 16], name="in_state")

        self.lstm_layer = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(16,forget_bias=1)
#             self.in_state = self.lstm_layer.zero_state(1, dtype=tf.float32) # By uncommenting this line the error is no longer there.
        self.out_rnn, self.rnn_state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(self.lstm_layer, \
                                                      tf.expand_dims(self.inputs_vec, 1), initial_state=self.in_state)

        self.output = tf.layers.dense(inputs = self.out_rnn, 
                                       kernel_initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer(),
                                      units = 5, 
                                    activation=None, name="output")

        self.action_distribution = tf.nn.softmax(self.output, name="softmax")

PGNetwork = PGNetwork(8)
```

I get this error :
`Tensor objects are not iterable when eager execution is not enabled. To iterate over this tensor use tf.map_fn.`

Which is actually there because of the `initial_state` in `tf.nn.dynamic_rnn()` since it is not accepted to be a placeholder.

Is it possible to convert the placeholder to something accepted by the `dynamic_rnn`????

Comment: if it is defined as a placeholder, you need to feed a value while training. Check [here](https://medium.com/@erikhallstrm/using-the-tensorflow-lstm-api-3-7-5f2b97ca6b73). Initial state can be initialized from zero and cell state/hidden state should be a tuple.

Comment: The network itself is erroneous , this is shown as it gives the error even before running the session. Anyway I knew how to deal with and I will post an answer for it shortly.

Comment: @mahmoudfathy could you please post an answer if you have one, thank you!

Comment: @omsrisagar I've gone back to my problem and it seems I found a way to use static_rnn instead. So Technically I have not found an answer to the question.